# Can silverlight finally substitute javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight

Maybe it sounds silly, but it seems to me that since silverlight and javascript both can only be executed on the browser, if the industry standard requires all the browsers to pre-install silverlight, can MS possibily create a new technology that can balance the C# code execution on server side and browser side? All the client and server side can be developed by .net only, and I don't need to develop the javacript anymore.

Is this possible? Or is there some hurdles that MS cannot overcome to abandon javascript?

Thanks,

Wei

Comment: what!?  i don't want to believe i'm reading this.

Comment: JavaScript has a lot more usage than the browser. It's getting quite popular for server-side code as well. Then there's also JSON, as well as the millions of apps with JS scripting.

Comment: I know this sound silly, but what I ask is only technically if it's possible. Is there any benefit or momentum that MS will do this?

Comment: I'm very happy developing on UNIX/LINUX based systems and have not touched MS products in years. I would like to continue doing so using open standard technologies I can develop for any platform using any platform. I do not intend to invest into one specific company's product just to be able to develop interactive websites, thank you very much.

Comment: Marked down because it seems like flame-bait.

Answer (score 3):

They solve completely different problems, but if anything Javascript has a greater chance of making Silverlight obsolete (along with AJAX etc.) than the other way around.

Also, there are MANY programmers who don't know (and don't care to know) the first thing about .NET.  Why would they want to be forced into MS development?

Comment: To the usage of AJAX, if .net code execution engine can be installed on all browser, I am sure MS can create a similar .net-based framework as AJAX. The biggest benefit for a .net developer is a better debugging support and one single coding language.

Comment: So you're saying MS should develop javascript with .net syntax?  Why reinvent a language that's been around for years, is well understood (as much as JS can be understood) and it works everywhere.  There are many languages out there because they are good at what they do.  Not one language can (and should) replace what exists today.

Comment: It's not replace, but for ASPX website, only one C# language is used (For now, the project contains both js and C# code). This can make develop ASP website much easier. Beside, there is no good js debug tool.

Comment: No debugging tools?  You are surely not serious.  Visual Studio itself is a great JS debugging tool, not to mention Firebug, Chrome Developer Tools, even IE 9 developer tools come with a very good JS debugger.  I am an ASP.NET developer by day, and it's already plenty easy with Javascript.

Comment: I'd say most programmers wouldn't be 'forced' into it, but if they don't want to work with .Net then they're just silly. .Net is better than alternatives more often than not.

Comment: @meds - "but if they don't want to work with .Net then they're just silly" please tell me you're joking (my sarcasm detector is off today I guess)